# Proof that $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2 | x_1>0, x_2>0 \}$ is an open set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have the following criteria:

If $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous, then the sets
$S_1=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n \ | \ f(x)>0 \}$, $S_2=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n \ | \ f(x)<0 \}$, 
$S_3=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n \ | \ f(x)\neq0 \}$ are open sets.

With those criteria I have to prove that the set in the title is open, but I have no idea how I could prove that. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Consider the projections on each factor: $\;(x,y)\mapsto x$ and $(x,y)\mapsto y$.

Comment: If $f$ is a continuous function and $A=(0,\infty)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$, then $f^{-1}(0,\infty)$ is the pre image of an open set, so $S_1$ is open

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, consider the projection maps, $\phi_x : (x,y)\mapsto x$, and $\phi_y:(x,y)\mapsto y$. These maps are clearly continuous. Now, the set you are interested in is nothing but, $\phi_x^{-1}(0,\infty)\cap \phi_y^{-1}(0,\infty)$, both of which are open sets (open set characterization of continuous maps). Now, (finite) intersection open sets is open, done.

Comment: Mh yes, but this isn't what I asked for. I have to prof this with one of the three give criteria..

Answer (score 0):

Prove that $$
f(x_1,x_2)=\begin{cases} x_1x_2 &\text{if } x_1>0, \;x_2 >0 \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $S_1=f^{-1}((0,\infty))$ and $S_2=S_1=f^{-1}((-\infty, 0)),\ $ and since $f$ is continuous, each is open in $\mathbb R^n$. Therefore, so is $S_3=S_1\cap S_2$.

Comment: And what would $f$ look like? I don't understand your proof, could you maybe explain it a bit more indepth?

Comment: All you know about $f$ is that it is continuous. But that is enough, because $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty, 0)$ are open in $\mathbb R$ so their inverse images by $f$ are open in $\mathbb R^n$ and then so is their intersection. And you're done!

Comment: But where is the connection to my give set with $x_1>0, x_2>0$?